# What's the difference between the LM2917 and the LM2917-N?

Tags: converter

The schematic I'm looking at says to use an LM2917. The  specs from the TI site use  both LM2917 and LM2917-N and the shop on ebay uses both names too.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/270864373784?lpid=82&chn=ps&ul_noapp=true

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2907-n.pdf

Is this some kind of naming convention I should know about for the future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

N is TI's designation for their Plastic DIP through hole package. Note that the SMD SOIC package designation is M.

Note, these are ***old*** ICs first designed by National Semi in the 1970s ([This App note](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snaa088/snaa088.pdf) is from 1976) and later cloned by ***everybody.*** TI eventually acquired NatSemi in the 2000s and absorbed their ICs into their product lines.

I believe but can't find the original first revision datasheets to confirm, that these ICs first came out when ***Ceramic*** DIP were still common, so the N designator for moulded plastic DIP was important to point out the difference. -8 at the end also designated it as the 8 pin version, so LM2917N-8 is the 8 pin PDIP.